# Deletion votes retroactively become irreversible when a user becomes a moderator

Tags: discussion, bug, moderators, deleted-questions

While browsing the 10K tools undeletion queue I just noticed that a handful of questions with two undeletion votes are now stuck in limbo, impossible to get the final undeletion vote, because they were deleted by users who later become mods in the recent election, and the deletion votes have been (effectively) retroactively granted moderator superpower. It is not clear that this is the intended behavior, esp. since many of the candidates wrote in campaign statements that do not desire to cast such superpower deletion votes. Does SE actually intend that such votes be retroactively redefined as moderator votes, or is this a bug?

Comment: Could you link such questions?

Comment: Also on Meta.SE: [Deletion votes from users who later became moderators shouldn't prevent community undeletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174860/).

Comment: @BillDubuque I don't see a reason to undelete those questions.

Comment: @Pedro This is not about the specific questions or anyone's views on them. Rather, it is about the *general issue* mentioned in the OP. Notice that no specific questions are mentioned in the OP. I supplied some instances only because you requested such. I have since removed them to avoid the discussion from further veering off-topic.

Comment: @Behaviour And, strangely enough, the question is highly upvoted on SO, but downvoted here. Hilarious.... Or maybe the downvotes represent disagreement with the SE behavior. Right, that's it!

Comment: That certainly seems like an undesirable behavior of the site, since being a moderator should mean you've *reached* a point where we trust your judgment, not that you were *always* there.

Comment: The discrepancy in reception might be due to the fact that a known issue is reported as a bug. Moreover, one might have considered to post on meta.SE right away, then this could just have been closed as a dupe.

Comment: The reply on meta.SE suggests this should be tagged [meta-tag:status-deferred] In the interim relevant cases could be handled on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @quid I don't believe it's (well) known *here*, and many posts here are closely related to those on meta.SE. Iirc SE encourages users to use their local meta site, since many (most?) local users do not read the global meta.SE. Doing so helps expose SE issues locally.

Comment: So what? It cannot be changed here. Would you ask how we should deal with this behavior it would be a legitimate discussion. "Does SE actually intend that such votes be retroactively redefined as unilateral, or is this a bug?" Is not a subject for a *discussion* but support or bug. Do you want an answer to this question? I, or anybody given the link, can post it right away? Normally you should post it now that you know. If you want something else you might explain what it is.

Comment: @quid It's a bug-report. That is one of the intended uses  of meta.

Comment: Okay that's fine. If it is only a bug report then please remove the discussion tag.

Comment: @quid It's not *only* a bug report. Presumably SE pays attention to community discussion, e.g. they may use such to hep prioritize their open bug list.

Comment: @BillDubuque then I repeat my question: what specifically do you want to discuss?

Comment: @quid Anyone is welcome to discuss whatever they may desire on this and related matters. For an analogous example, a half-year ago when I raised the issue about not being able to undelete Community deleted posts, eventually this percolated to SE and they quickly fixed this bug (this too was known long prior on SO). Presumably the quick resolution was sparked by *discussion* here about how this bug was being exploited by the massive deletion campaign. In any case, there are plenty of questions here tagged both bug and discussion.

Comment: I would delete the "many of the candidates wrote in campaign statements that do not desire to cast unilateral deletion votes.", which is irrelevant since none of the new mods wrote something like that.

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/elusion. I'd also like to point out that posting two questions in one (so here, a bug report plus a discussion on an unknown matter) is generally frowned upon, even on meta. There are only [25 questions tagged bug and discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+discussion) out of 4551 -- hardly "plenty".

Comment: Finally it's a bit unclear to me why a bug report should contain a political statement. You might consider that who posts the bug report and the way it is laid out can influence voting behavior. Would you go to IT and report a bug like that?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Nobody said anything about "bug reports containing political statements" nor "posting two questions on one". Please stay on-topic.

Comment: "Anyone is welcome to discuss whatever they may desire on this and related matters." speaks for it self. I will try to leave this non-constructive post now.

Comment: What? *I* said something about "bug reports containing political statement". Your bug report contains a political statement. *I* said something about posting two questions on one. Your question apparently contains at the same time a bug report and a call for discussion. Am I only allowed to talk about what other people have commented about? My remarks are on-topic, they're directly about your question.

Comment: @Najib Both are quite off-topic here (as are many comments above). If you wish to discuss them please have the courtesy to open a new meta post.

Comment: Okay, I can see having a reasonable discussion is not possible and that I've been wasting my time.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker fyi from  campaign statements: Dan Fischer wrote "being elected would end my casting delete votes there, it's up to [...] the community".
Jyrki Lahtonen wrote "as a moderator I will not use my binding vote on such a questiona [...] I like to leave this to the community". Kudos to Dan and Jyrki.

Comment: @Najib Thee is no "political statement" in the OP. Politics was dragged into the matter only in the tangential comments - which is one common tactic for diverting discussions. Alas that happens far too often on meta these days.

Comment: @BillDubuque The "there" in your quote of Dan refers to the quue for delete votes. Jyrki also made his statement in context " My own sentiment is that correct ≠ useful. However, as a moderator I will not use my binding vote on such a question." There is a difference between being more careful with ones votes and campaigning for mod with a promis never to delete something, which would make little sense.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I stand firmly by my remark, which is directly supported by said quotes. If you wish to discuss these matters further please do it in a more appropriate place - this thread is for the topic in the OP - not for such matters.

Comment: @BillDubuque What is probably true is that they did not intend for their deletion votes pre-mod becoming binding. What is not true is that they "do not desire to cast unilateral deletion votes", which is part of being a moderator.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I don't agree. In any case, the quotes make my point, so let's leave it at that - these comments have already veered very far off-topic.

Comment: I'm not going to waste my time further. If you're just going to deny reality, I can do nothing. Just noting that calling differing opinions or criticism "off-topic" is also a diversion tactic. Your bug report is a duplicate, your call for discussion is useless considering you're inviting everyone to talk about everything and refuse to narrow it down. Let's leave it at that.

Comment: @Najib Those "differing opinions" are on topics that are not about the *very specific* issue targeted in the OP. If you wish to discuss such highly tangential topics then please do so in the appropriate thread. Attempting to discuss such contentious matters here will only serve to swamp rational discussion of the specific topic in the OP. It has already greatly influenced the voting (compare the votes on meta.SE), so that they are now probably meaningless.

Comment: If this is truly just a bug report, then minimal is better, so the "esp. since..." clause doesn't belong, since it doesn't describe the bug, but instead tries to persuade that it is not a feature. I presume Bill expected disagreement over whether it's a bug, thus the call for discussion. In light of the responses, the comment should probably be removed; there doesn't seem to be need for persuasion, but there is disagreement over its veracity, and some feeling that Bill is exploiting the chance to emphasize something that aligns with the views he espouses on what proper moderation should be.

Comment: I wonder whether there is the same problem with [dupehammer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dupehammer).

Comment: @MartinSleziak I quite strongly believe all closures are reversible by normal users (this is definitely the case for common moderator closures), so there should be never an issue. I might misunderstand your concern though.

Comment: @quid Of course you are right that the vote is reversible. I am just wondering whether the following scenario is possible: I case a vote (before getting gold badge) which is not the fifth vote. Then I get gold badge and the dupehammer with it. My vote changes to binding vote, so the question is closed without waiting for 5 users. (And I certainly agree that it is not clear whether this would indeed be for some reason a problem.)

Comment: @Martin Retroactively redefining meaning can lead to all sorts of problems, e.g. suppose I cast the lone dupe close vote on a question a few years ago. Now I get a gold badge there. I wouldn't want it to automatically close that question, because my view on such closures has changed much since 3 years ago. When I cast that vote I cast it knowing precisely what it meant. It is wrong to retroactively change that meaning.

Comment: Further there are probably some users who are uncomfortable using such superpowers and may choose never to do so - preferring a more democratic process. It would probably offend them if their votes were retroactively redefined to be superpower votes.

Comment: @Najib Read closer. I made no such claim. My discussion in the prior few comments is about (possibly) retroactive gold-badge superpowers.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I highly doubt that things happen in the way that "pending votes" (so votes cast that did not yet take effect) change retroactively; neither for gold-hammer nor for mod (nor for related things one could envision). I believe that the type/weight of vote is decided at the time it is cast, and then it is not updated if some user's status changes. The issue why the deletion is irreversible should be that at the time the undelete vote is cast it is checked if the delete happened by a user with mod privilege and there is some issue their (not because the vote 'itself' changed).

Comment: Further, *even if* the dupe-vote would change, the situation would be less dramatic then one might get the impression from OP's scenario. *Typically* votes to close age-away within a couple of days (there are some exception for very low view posts). That is, the votes that would become "activated" would  be recent ones, not votes from years ago; except maybe in extreme corner cases.

Comment: Tangentially, since "democratic process" was mentioned. Voting to close and voting to delete is not intended as a democratic process to begin with; "vote" is really a misnomer there. That more than one vote of a normal user is needed is not to get some better approximation to the majorities point of view but for redundancy to saveguard against errors or rogue behavior. This is as much about democracy as having more than one lock at ones front-door is.

Answer (score 22):

Robert Cartaino, Director of Community Development [commented on this subject some time ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174978):

> No, I don't (personally) believe all **previous** actions of a user should become "Moderator actions" (capitol 'M') once they gain that diamond ♦. [...]
>
> In that same vein, any official actions taken by a moderator♦ should *not* suddenly become *un-official*, should they relinquish their position.
>
> As for handling these cases, it may be an oversight… a bug… or just one of those pedantic, edge cases not worth devoting the resources to *right now.* That's a discussion for another party.

It appears that SE is aware of this issue and possibly considers it as a bug, yet fixing it not a priority. Since some time elapsed it might make sense to recall that this is an open problem.

Comment: Credit should be given to user Behaviour, who found said related Meta.SE question and posted the link as the second comment to the OP.

Comment: I would add a bounty there, but (a) I already have three active bounties there; and (b) Christmas Eve is not the best time in terms of getting SE employees' attention. I'll post a bounty later if nobody else does.

Comment: @BillDubuque I credited Behaviour in a comment on main before posting this answer. I considered this as sufficient. I however made it CW now.

Comment: In comparison to other site events, [user becomes moderator] is unbelievably infrequent. As long as nothing extreme is breaking during this process, my guess is that it's not going to be fixed soon.